# Pika & RabbitMQ - Async Class Handler

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm trying to create a class which will be able to construct, and return an object which is callable at certain points of time and sending message to RabbitMQ

I'm using Pika and I've tried this code but it won't initiate unless i call ioloop but i don't need one and ioloop stucks the rest of my code which is called this class.

any ideas how to achieve that?

```
import pika
```

import ConfigurationManager
import json
import gc

class MessageSender:

```
def __init__(self,brokerUrl,queueName):
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('admin', 'admin')        
    self.brokerUrl = brokerUrl
    self.queueName = queueName        
    self.channel = None
    self.connectionParameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=self.brokerUrl, credentials=credentials)
    self.connection = pika.SelectConnection(self.connectionParameters, on_open_callback=self.onOpen, custom_ioloop=None)                        

def onOpen(self, connection):
    connection.channel(self.openChannel)

def openChannel(self, channel):
    channel.queue_declare(None, queue=self.queueName, durable=True) 
    self.channel = channel

def createMessageJson(self,commandType,searchId,senderChannel,data,runId=None, originalMessage=None):
    rtnDict = {}
    rtnDict["commandType"] = commandType
    rtnDict["searchId"] = searchId
    rtnDict["receipientChannel"]  = self.queueName
    rtnDict["senderChannel"] = senderChannel
    rtnDict["data"] = data
    if 'executionPlanSchema' in data:
        rtnDict['executionPlanSchema'] = data['executionPlanSchema']
    if runId != None:
        rtnDict["runId"] = runId
    if originalMessage != None:
        rtnDict["originalMessage"] = originalMessage
    return rtnDict

#def sendMessage(self,msg):
#    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(lambda: self.send(msg))

def sendMessageAsync(self,msg):
    msg = json.dumps(msg)
    self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key=self.queueName, body=msg)    
    gc.collect()

def sendMessage(self,msg):
    msg = json.dumps(msg)
    self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key=self.queueName, body=msg)
    gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`BlockingConnection`](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/comparing_publishing_sync_async.html) instead.